# Bootstrap grid system does not work in MacOS Safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website. In all devices Bootstrap grid system works well. However, in safari MacOS it does not work properly.

[image]

Where can be the problem? Here is the website:

1) https://www.wtf.az/courses

and this

2) https://www.wtf.az/courses/category/foreign-languages

Answer (score 1):

https://www.wtf.az/courses/category/foreign-languages

```
div class="row list-group col-md-12 easyPaginateList" id="products"
```

Try to change class `row` to `row-fluid`